# GitLab run pipeline only if change on root files

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In project's setting for merge request we have option **Pipelines must succeed** checked. So any merge request that does not produce pipeline cannot be merged.

However, majority of files on root do not actually need a pipeline but because the condition above, there needs to be a job defined for changes there also. What we want to do, is to run a specific empty job only when there are changes on root files and not run it if there are changes in folders and subfolders as well (since these changes already trigger the pipeline). So as example:

```
folder/subfolder/files
folder/file
file1
file2
```

If only file1 or/and file2 is changed **run** the job.

If file1 or/and file2 and folder are changed, **do not run** the job.

Current definition would be like that, but it does not work:

```
root_changes:
  stage: pre_build
  image: alpine:latest
  tags: ...
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script: date
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID'
      changes:
        - ./**/*
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID'
      changes:
        - ./*
      when: always
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` but inside double quotes to avoid formatting issues. Something like this:

```
rules:
- changes:
    - "*"
```